# Div animation with Javascript after clicking on a link - how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, hyperlink

I would like to animate a div after clicking on a link. When you click on "About", the  should change its height. Height is set to '0em' in the CSS file. It works if I write "document.getElementById('about-div').style.height = '';", but it will jump suddenly, not animated. Now I tried this code but unfortunately, it doesn't want to work:

CSS:

```
.about-div {position:absolute;top:100vh;left:0em;width:100vw;height:0em;z-index:10000;background:white;overflow:hidden;}

.open {
  -webkit-animation: open 1s ease-in 1 forwards;
  animation: open 1s ease-in 1 forwards;
}

.is-paused {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes open {
  0%   {height:0em;}
  1%     {height:'';}
  100% {height:'';}
}

@-webkit-keyframes open {
  0%   {height:0em;}
  1%     {height:'';}
  100% {height:'';}
}

@keyframes close {
  0%   {height:'';}
  100% {height:0em;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes close {
  0%   {height:'';}
  100% {height:0em;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:openAbout()">About</a>

<div class="about-div open is-paused">
   <p>Some Content</p>
</div>
```

...and the Javascript code:

```
function openAbout()  {
  <script>
    document.querySelector('.about-div').classList.remove('is-paused');
  </script>
}
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: Remove the `<script>` tags inside your `openAbout()` function. There should only be `<script>` tags around your whole JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/uk15255k/).

You should remove the `script` tags from inside your JS function. All parts of your JS should be inside the script tags like below.

```
<script>
function openAbout() {
    document.querySelector('.about-div').classList.remove('is-paused');
}
</script>
```

Also, I think using animation to animate the height is a bit cumbersome, so I used transition instead. Please see demo below (I removed the bottom positioning for easier viewing, you can put it back when you use it).

```js
function openAbout() {
    document.querySelector('.about-div').classList.remove('is-paused');
}
```

```css
body { background: #ddd; }
.about-div {
    position:absolute;
    left:0em;
    width:100vw;
    z-index:10000;
    background:white;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: max-height 5s;
}
.open {
    max-height: 999px;
}
.is-paused {
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="openAbout()">About</a>

<div class="about-div open is-paused">
    <p>Some Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: previously, it worked, then I modified with a few things in the CSS i think and now it don't want to work anymore.. I mean, the link will open the div, and when you resize the screen (so the div too), the text moves animatedly to the center of the div... but the height of the div won't be animated, it just jumps to the desired size immediately. [link] (http://paperdeermusic.com)

Do you have any idea what happens?

Comment: What did you edit? The max-height is the key to the animation, it needs to be 0px at the start, and 999px (any height that is more than your desired height) for the class that is left when clicked.

Comment: nothing else... I mean, I edited it because if I give a max-height, it won't fit the content, so I wrote it like " height:' ' " when it is opened. And the closed one is " height:0px ". I think the problem is not with this because when I use max-height, it is neither animated, it jumps.

The code:

CSS:

Comment: The code:

CSS:
    #widget-about {
      position:absolute;
      top:100vh;
      left:0em;
      width:100vw;
      z-index:10000;
      background:white;
      overflow:hidden;
    }

    .open {
     height:'';
    }

    .closed {
        height: 0px;
     }

HTML:
    <a href=# onclick="openAbout()">About</a>

    <div id="widget-about" class="open closed">
            <div class="global-widget-style">
      content
            </div>
    </div>

Script:
     function openAbout()  {
      document.querySelector('#widget-about').classList.remove('closed');
    }

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to be in script tags, not script tags inside the function.

```
<script>
function openAbout()  {
    document.querySelector('.about-div').classList.remove('is-paused');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first:

'href' isn't intended for calling functions. Most HTML elements have an 'onclick' tag for doing that.

```
<a href="#" onclick="openAbout()">About</a>
```

And you need to remove the '' tags like mentioned so your code looks like:

```
function openAbout() {
    document.querySelector('.about div').classList.remove('is-paused');
}
```